# What is our policy on material recommendations?

Tags: discussion, scope

From time to time we get questions asking for a material with certain properties, like [this one](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7668/hard-coating-for-soft-surface) or [this one](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4274/easily-removable-material-that-sticks-to-skin) or [this one](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/which-materials-compounds-expand-in-response-to-cold-temperatures).

Many of these garner a couple of close votes, and they do attract [discussions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7668/hard-coating-for-soft-surface#comment11198_7668) on their ontopicness.

Should these be on topic? More accurately, what qualities should we look for in such questions to make them on topic?